# Qt Баг с точностью после запятой в таблицах

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, tableview

Привет Всем, столкнулся с такой проблемой, во всех таблицах, базовых примерах да и вообще Qt почему то допускает писать в таблицах значения только с точностью два знака после запятой, не более. 
Как пример возьмем стандартный пример в Qt sqlbrowser.
Запускаем пример, заходим, видим в дереве 2 элемента Movies и Names, заходим в Movies, далее в колонке Rating видим значения:
Например: 8,1
Нужно: 8,0001  , но больше двух цифр не вбивается после запятой, так во всех примерах QT.
Вопрос как данную проблему исправить, основываясь на этом примере?
Желательно привести данный участок кода, который разрешит эту проблему.

Comment: ключевое слово делегат

Answer (score 8):

Это не баг, а просто соглашение, принятое в Qt по умолчанию для чисел с плавающей точкой. В одной задаче нужно показывать один знак после запятой, в другой все девяносто девять.

Если не подходит количество, принятое по умолчанию, то создают собственный делегат - виджет, который предоставляет пользователю не только альтернативный вид данных в таблице, но и их редактирование.

Файл **delegate.h**:

```
#ifndef DELEGATE_H
#define DELEGATE_H

#include <QtWidgets/QStyledItemDelegate>

class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Delegate(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

        virtual QString displayText(const QVariant &value
            , const QLocale &locale) const;

        virtual QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent
            , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

        virtual void setEditorData(QWidget *editor
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

        virtual void setModelData(QWidget *editor
            , QAbstractItemModel *model
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif
```

Файл **delegate.cpp**:

```
#include "delegate.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox>

Delegate::Delegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

QString Delegate::displayText(const QVariant &value
    , const QLocale &locale) const {

    Q_UNUSED(locale);

    // Шесть знаков после запятой.
    return QString::number(value.toDouble(), 'f', 6);

    // Если нет необходимости в том, чтобы поле таблицы
    // содержало заканчивающие числа нули, то вместо
    // аргумента `f` нужно указать значение `g`.

    // return QString::number(value.toDouble(), 'g', 6);
}

QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    Q_UNUSED(option); Q_UNUSED(index);

    QDoubleSpinBox *editor = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);

    // Шесть знаков после запятой.
    editor->setDecimals(6);

    return editor;
}

void Delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QDoubleSpinBox *sbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    if(sbox != Q_NULLPTR) {
        sbox->setValue(index.model()
            ->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble());
    }
}

void Delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor
    , QAbstractItemModel *model
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QDoubleSpinBox *sbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    if(sbox != Q_NULLPTR) {
        model->setData(index, sbox->value(), Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
```

В методе `Delegate::createEditor()` строка `editor->setDecimals(6)` установит для делегата шесть знаков после запятой.

Установка делегата в виджет таблицы:

```
QTableView *view = new QTableView();
view->setModel(model);
view->setItemDelegate(new Delegate(view));
```

Comment: Спасибо сделал, всё работает, но теперь проблема в следующем: Автоматически дополнеются шесть нулей всегда, например ввожу 8.63 отображает 8.630000, а мне нужно что бы отображалась столько цифр сколько ты задал, например 8.634, без дополнительных нулей.

Comment: Дополнил ответ в методе `Delegate::displayText()`.

Comment: Это я понял, я имел ввиду по двойному клику, при редактировании, сори если не так выразился вначале.

Comment: Боюсь, здесь Вам придётся наследовать `QAbstractSpinBox` и переопределять поведение в соответствии с тем, как это требуется в Вашей задаче. Возможно, что я не прав, пусть тогда меня поправят, но иного пути, пожалуй, нет.

Comment: Как правильно сделать наследование QDoubleSpinBox с переопределением метода textFromValue, вроде он работает, но криво.  ``MyDoubleSpinBox::MyDoubleSpinBox(QObject *parent) {}

QString MyDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue(double value) const
    {
        QString text = QDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue(value);
        text = QString::number(value,'g',6);
        return text;
    } ``

Comment: Криво возможно по той причине, что нужно также переопределить и `valueFromText()`, которая из строки возвратит число. А базовую `textFromValue()` внутри своего метода вызывать наверное не нужно.

Comment: Попробовал сам. Думаю, проблема не вполне простая, несмотря на то, что кажется обратное. Вполне достойна отдельного вопроса. Возможно, что кто-нибудь ещё подключится.

Comment: вроде так работает в h добавляем  ``class MyDoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyDoubleSpinBox(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    QString textFromValue(double value) const;
    //double valueFromText(const QString& text) const;
};``        А в cpp файл  ``MyDoubleSpinBox::MyDoubleSpinBox(QWidget *parent) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent){}   QString MyDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue(double value) const
{
    QString str = locale().toString(value, 'g', 6);
    if (qAbs(value) >= 1000.0) {
        str.remove(locale().groupSeparator());
    }
    return str;
}``

Comment: alexis031182 отпишись если получится) возможно что нибудь лучше придумаешь) т.к не могу нормально работать с ``valueFromText``,  исходники смотрел ``QDoubleSpinBox`` и ``QDoubleSpinBoxPrivate`` по этому поводу, но и без него работает вроде как)