# Qt Автоопределение Делегатов для столбцов или ячеек

Tags: c++, qt, mvc

Работаю с QSqlTableModel, делаю 3 делегата QDoubleSpinBox, QLineEdit, QDateTime переопределяю стандартные методы. Проблема в том, что данные делегаты можно задать только 1) для всей таблицы 2) для конкретных столбцов 3) для конкретных строк. Но у меня данные из таблицы подгружаются из Postgres БД и там десятки таблиц. 
Мне нужно что бы по нажатию на ячейку, пвтоматически определялся ее тип, к примеру если там содержится строка QString он применяет QLineEdit делегаг, а если там вещественные числа QDoubleSpinBox, если время 30.05.2016 то делегат QDateTime.
Как данная реализация будет выглядеть в коде? есть примеры?

Или как сделать так, есть делегат QDoubleSpinBox, нужно что бы он применялся не ко всей таблице а только к ячейкам где тип double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взять [реализацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526712/qt-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85) обычного делегата, то её модификация для поддержки нескольких типов данных не должна быть сложной. Модель всегда возвращает данные в виде `QVariant`, который в свою очередь имеет метод `QVariant::type()`. Тогда, опираясь на получаемый тип данных, остаётся лишь создавать и возвращать соответствующий виджет:

```
QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    Q_UNUSED(option);

    QWidget *wdg = Q_NULLPTR;

    if(index.data().type() == QVariant::Double)
        wdg = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
    else if(index.data().type() == QVariant::String)
        wdg = new QLineEdit(parent);
    else if(index.data().type() == QVariant::Int)
        wdg = new QSpinBox(parent);    
    // и т.д. else if ...

    return wdg;
}
```

Соответствующим образом потребуется переопределить у делегата `setEditorData()` и `setModelData()`.

Comment: alexis, выражаю благодарность, ты помог

Comment: @DavidRise , нет проблем.